# detecting notificationbox close event - firefox addons

Tags: firefox-addon

We are using  to display custom notifications for a
Firefox addon.  All is good, except that we also need to do some custom
cleanup activity when the user presses the red [x] button (in Windows)
on the right side of our notification bar to close it (or technically
"hide" it).

That said, what would be the best way to detect or get an indication
that the user has pressed the red [x] button to close/hide the
notification?

There is this event AlertClose as the document say but how to handle it?

i tried this but no effect..

```
notificationobj.addEventListener('AlertClose',function() { alert('closed'); },false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad news is the "AlertClose" is only fired in Firefox Mobile. We should move the event to the toolkit so all apps get the support. I don't have any good ideas, except using a DOM mutation event to watch for "DOMNodeRemoved".

Comment: ok. could you drop me some references to DOM MUtation ... external links which would have examples... ?

Comment: Yeah that is working fine but how to find whether the user had clicked the red colored close button. The event fires when we click on that bar and on the buttons including the red close button.